# Eclipse PDE, create controls

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

From the very helpful templates I´ve got some controls. But how do I discover where those controls are located.

For example I know how to create a label or a button but how can I find a checkbox or add a browser to a button a List Box ...

Isn´t there any documentation where a developer can find those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy_menu) to see how those control are referenced in other plugins, in order to replicate that in your own plugins.

[image: plugin spy]

Comment: Very good hint, thanks! Isn´t there any further documentation? If I´d like to get a checkbox control I can´t get the information about it with the plugin spy because it´s only for the eclipse UI not for Submenus like new project editors.

Comment: @Nautis: you can start be reusing existing template, as described in http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/01/13/eclipse-papercut-7-adding-the-pde-plugin-creation-wizard-to-the-eclipse-toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

> For example I know how to create a label or a button but how can I find a checkbox or add a browser to a button a List Box ...

A checkbox is a `Button` with the `SWT.CHECK` style.

> Isn't there any documentation where a developer can find those things?

I bought an SWT book.  The Definitive Guide to SWT and JFace.